# Read one line from input file per iteration

Tags: java, loops, file-io, line

**Task:** read a line from an input file. If the first word of the line is PRINT, then print the contents of the rest of the line.

**Code:**

```
else if(Data.compareTo("PRINT") == 0){
    while(inFile.hasNext()){   
        Data = inFile.next();
        System.out.print( Data + " ");
    }
}
```

**Question:** How to code the scanner so that the scanner only reads one line of information at a time?

Comment: You should add a tag for which language your code is written in

Comment: What is the type of `inFile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void ReadAndProcessPrint(File fileToRead) throws FileNotFoundException {
    java.util.Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileToRead);
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if(line.startsWith("PRINT")){
            String restOfLine = line.substring(5);
            System.out.println(restOfLine);
        }else{
            //do other things
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hint: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Create a InputStreamReader and using it create a BufferedReader, use readLine method.